# Unexpected T_Variable with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I get this mistake

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$xml2' (T_VARIABLE) in /users/craftamap/www/craft_cms/index.php on line 4
```

by using this code.

```
if (file_exists("xml/sites.xml")) {
    $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("xml/sites.xml");
}
```

I can't figure out the mistake. The file is existing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code works for me. You have to give more context.

Comment: maybe post the sites.xml file

Comment: I think you are accessing the variable named $xml2 while the file not exists.

Comment: It's a parse error, it doesn't matter if the file exists or not, it does not matter what it contains; the code is not interpreted. But the exposed code doesn't have errors. Please post more context

Comment: Line 4 is line 2 here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sites>
<site1>
 <id>1</id><name>index</name>
 <title>Index</title>
 <filelocation>xml/index/index.xml</filelocation>
 <nav>true</nav>
 </site1>
<site2> <id>2</id>
<name>about</name>
 <title>About</title>
 <nav>true</nav>
</site2>
</sites>     this is the XML file

Comment: There is no way this error is caused by `$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("xml/sites.xml");`, I really don't want to accept that :), can you give us more details?

Comment: http://craftamap.bplaced.net/craft_cms/index.txt here you can see the whole script as txt file

Comment: Try to replace `$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("xml/sites.xml");` with "$xml1 = simplexml_load_string("<parent><child>child1</child></parent>");` just exclude the idea that the error is coming from `simplexml_load_file()`